# Fbx animation without bones or single skeleton

Tags: xna, models

SkinnedModel sample nicely shows how to import single root bone skeleton and run in XNA.

My question are:

1. Is it possible to have animations played in XNA if there no bones are used in model (which can easily be done in 3dmax with auto key frames)?
2. Is it possible to have multiple independent bones laying around, connected to independent meshes and animated, all played in XNA?
3. Can SkinnedModelProcessor be downgraded to this level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should look at [XNAnimation](http://www.brunoevangelista.com/projects/), it extends on the original samples to provide a more comprehensive set of animation possibilities.

Beware though, it was discontinued at some point, although it's now looking active again. Somebody took it up to port it to the SunBurn rendering engine: [sgMotion](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/Framework/Download_sgMotion_Animation_Library.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at these projects. This example project also cover most of my question http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_rigid_and_skinned

Comment: The samples are nice, but too limited for real games, ie, you have to expand on them a lot to support everything. Which might be what you want, or not :)

Answer (score 1):

In Max, you can actually asign a mesh a single bone, that has rigidly asigned or linked a mesh or vertices, and animate bone's traslations/rotations (or use dummies). Using auto keyframe or not. The mesh will follow it, as is linked. I guess later on importing the skinned mesh into XNA will treat it like always, it would see no difference, but you actually handled them as if were moving just static meshes, in Max. If there can be two skinned meshes at a time in xna, then you should be able to do this, and with more than two.